# JQuery script on an Asp.Net Web User Control Executes More Than Once

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have some javascript on a web user control and instantiate two instances of that control on a page. The control is just to show some help text and should toggle to open or close.

The document.ready function goes as expected in that it runs twice. However when I click on either control the script runs twice and thus the control opens then closes.

How do I make sure the script only runs once for the control that is clicked.

```
<div class="helpControlHolder">
    <div class="expandableHeading">Show (Hide) </div>
    <div class="expandableContent commentsTable" >
        <ul id="ulComments" runat="server"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function slideToggle(e, ui) {
            debugger;
            //find the right control to slideToggle
            var ct = e.currentTarget;
            var controlHolder = ct.parentNode;  //up the dom one element
            $(controlHolder).find(".expandableContent").slideToggle(500); //back down the dom to the element we want to animate

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //find the right control to hide
        var pare = $('.helpControlHolder');
        pare.find(".expandableContent").hide();

        pare.find(".expandableHeading").click(function (e, ui) {
            e.preventDefault();
            slideToggle(e, ui);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I will suggest you to put JavaScript code in a seprate file

Comment: Since `document ready` is called twice, your `click()` handler is bound twice which is causing the issue

Comment: You are using class selector this mean 2 element are found on the page   I would suggest you to make container run at server, give a Id and in the selector use '#<%= Div_Id.ClientID %>'

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to change your javascript as follows:

<script type="text/javascript">
    function slideToggle(e, ui) {
            debugger;
            //find the right control to slideToggle
            var ct = e.currentTarget;
            var controlHolder = ct.parentNode;  //up the dom one element
            $(controlHolder).find(".expandableContent").slideToggle(500); //back down the dom to the element we want to animate

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //find the right control to hide
        var pare = $('.helpControlHolder');
        pare.find(".expandableContent").hide();


    });
   $(function(){
    $(".expandableHeading").click(function (e, ui) {
            e.preventDefault();
            slideToggle(e, ui);
    });
   });
</script>


Hope it helps.
```

Comment: @Satpal - putting script in separate file doesn't solve the problem in itself.

Comment: @UmairP - yes that's right it is the problem, the script was on each control so was being added twice. But how to solve the problem?

Comment: To solve this problem I moved the script to a separate file and then I added an entry to the Site Scripts section of the master page as follows:

Answer (score 0):

The problem was (as pointed out by @UmairP) the script was being added twice to the page. I moved the script to a separate file (helpControl.js) and then added the following entry to the Site Scripts section of the Master Page I was using:

```
<%--Site Scripts--%>
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/C/helpControl.js" />
```

This means it only gets added once and runs as expected.

Thanks for replies